# Spliting object using reflection

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

I have the following object type

```
public class TestClass
{
    public string Property_1;
    public string Property_2;
    public int property_3;
    public DateTime TimeStame;
}
```

And my data source is returning a list of these

```
List<TestClass> DataResponse;
```

I am trying to group all data so that all Property_1's are grouped by date, and the same for all other properties. So essentially I end up with:

```
Dictionary<DateTime, List<Property_1>>
Dictionary<DateTime, List<Property_2>>
Dictionary<DateTime, List<Property_3>>
```

I can iterate the properties using:

```
foreach (var property in typeof(TestClass).GetProperties())
{

}
```

But I am a little unsure how to use linq to populate the dictionaries.

Any help would be great! 
Thanks

Comment: Do you know the property names in advance?  If so, don't use reflection, just write a simple LINQ statement to do it.  If this is for an arbitrary class with N properties + one more named TimeStamp, then build a list of MethodImpl objects that reference the property getters (build the list outside the loop).  Then, in the loop, use each MethodImpl to read the property  That some of your properties are string and some are int is going to complicate your life

Comment: Your dictionary declarations are wrong.  `Property_N` is a property name, not a type.  And, you aren't going to have a `Dictionary<DateTime, List<TypeOfProperty1>>`, you are going to end up with a `Dictionary<DateTime, TypeOfProperty1> unless I'm very confused

Comment: And...You probably don't even want a Dictionary.  I'm guessing you want this as a time-series, with TimeStamp/Value pairs.  Dictionaries don't have an order guarantee (if you enumerate a dictionary, you don't necessarily get things in the same order you inserted stuff into the collection).  You probably want `List<KeyValuePair<DateTime, TypeOfPropertyN>>`.  That's a good representation of a time series

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess something like this should do the trick

```
var prop1 = new Dictionary<DateTime, List<string>>();
var prop2 = new Dictionary<DateTime, List<string>>();
var prop3 = new Dictionary<DateTime, List<int>>();

foreach (var grouped in list.GroupBy(l => l.TimeStamp))
{
    prop1.Add(grouped.Key, grouped.Select(i => i.Property_1).ToList());
    prop2.Add(grouped.Key, grouped.Select(i => i.Property_2).ToList());
    prop3.Add(grouped.Key, grouped.Select(i => i.Property_3).ToList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Original**

*Reflection* seems overkill. You could just use `ToDictionary`

```
var result1 = DataResponse.ToDictionary(x => x.Property_1);
var result2 = DataResponse.ToDictionary(x => x.Property_2);
var result3 = DataResponse.ToDictionary(x => x.Property_3);
```

If you need more granularity over the group, use `GroupBy`

if you want to quantize the date without time, you could use `x.Property_3.Date`

---

**Updated**

However thinking this through, you should probably just use `GroupBy`

```
var result1 = DataResponse.GroupBy(x => x.Property_1);
var result2 = DataResponse.GroupBy(x => x.Property_2);
var result3 = DataResponse.GroupBy(x => x.Property_3);

...

foreach(var result in result1)
{
    // do something with your groups
}
```